# Saving png file as 16 or 32 bit using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, label, pixel

I am reading an image using opencv. Its a RGB masked image with pixels in between 0 - 255.

```
testImg = cv2.imread("testImg.png", -1)
np.unique(testImg)

# Output
array([ 0,  1,  4,  7,  9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], dtype=uint8)
```

I want to change the pixels b/w 0 to 5000 and thus modified the numpy array dtype to int16.

```
testImg = testImg.astype('int16')
np.unique(testImg)

#Output
array([ 0,  1,  4,  7,  9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], dtype=int16)
```

I modify the pixel values:

```
testImg = testImg * 100
np.unique(testImg)

# Output
array([   0,  100,  400,  700,  900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1500, 1600, 1700,
       1800, 1900], dtype=int16)
```

When debugging I can see that the modified pixel values are reflected correctly into the image array. However, when I write it into a png file, values are truncated to int8.

```
cv2.imwrite("testImg16Bit.png", testImg)

testImg16Bit = cv2.imread("testImg16Bit.png", -1)

np.unique(testImg16Bit)

# Output
array([  0, 100, 255], dtype=uint8)
```

Any suggestions on what am I missing here or any other approach?

thanks!

EDIT:

Instead of saving file as int16, i saved it as uint16 and then the image is stored correctly!! What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

You did

```
cv2.imwrite("testImg16Bit.png", testImg)
testImg16Bit = cv2.imread("testImg16Bit.png", -1)
```

i.e. there are two distinct action which might cause changing to 8-bits that is *writing* and *reading*. For second default action is converting to 8-bit to avoid that use `cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH` flag, in your case

```
testImg16Bit = cv2.imread("testImg16Bit.png", flags=cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
```

If this does not help use some other software than OpenCV to determine if created file is actually 16-bit, if not you need to improve writing too.

Comment: It does not help. 'np.unique(cv2.imread("testImg16Bit.png", flags=cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH))
# Output
array([ 0, 29, 76], dtype=uint8)'

Comment: @blackbug then please check if png image created is actually 16-bit using software other than OpenCV

Comment: I saved the image as uint16 instead of int16, and everything works. I can see the file size is larger and can be read also as uint16 without loosing values..no idea why it works..

Comment: @blackbug negative values for pixels generally does not make sense, but this lead to question what action was stealthily done by `imwrite` and why it did not issue any warning

Comment: @Daweo The [documentation of `imwrite`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce): "In general, only 8-bit single-channel or 3-channel (with 'BGR' channel order) images can be saved using this function, with these exceptions: * 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) images can be saved in the case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF formats .... If the image format is not supported, the image will be converted to 8-bit unsigned (CV_8U) and saved that way." | Signed 16-bit is not mentioned as exception, so it's unsupported, and automatically converted.

Comment: @DanMašek thanks for explanation, please consider adding this information as separate answer